# 3D Model Browser viewer

Tags: javascript, cad

I am in need of a good model viewer for our site. I need a way to show models of teeth, and have the ability to turn off different layers such as the Enamel, Dentin, and just show the nerve/blood supply. I would love the ability to do transparencies and slices through XYZ coordinates.

That is just one example of course, there are a few other things I am trying to put together that utilize 3D. I have been looking all over github, and some paid solutions as well, but haven't found anything yet.

GrabCad has an amazing viewer, not sure if it is custom or just just customized from a paid service. We don't have any art specifically yet, but will probably work with models from places like turbosquid and have modifications made for us. I mention this because I am currently very flexible with what format is supported by the viewer.

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be most appreciative.